# Android Retrofit renders 401 error at just one specific request

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-4, http-status-code-401, retrofit2

I'm working on a simple android application which gets its data from a Rails restful API.

Up to a certain moment, my application is able to perform quite a few requests that are authenticated ones from my rails rest api.

I'm passing my authentication headers with an interceptor, as required from Retrofit documentation:

```
public static MyRestService getServiceWithHeaders(Context context){
    applicationContext = context;

    Response result = null;

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
    session = new UserSessionManager(applicationContext);
    final User u = session.getUser();

    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okClient.interceptors().add(logging);
    okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            if (u.email != null) {                    
                Request original = chain.request();

                //my authentication headers!!
                Request newRequest = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("X-User-Email", u.email)
                        .header("X-User-Token", u.authentication_token)
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .build();                    
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            } else {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                return response;
            }
        }
    });


    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okClient)
            .build();        
    return client.create(ConsbrService.class);
}
```

With these authenticated headers, everything seems to work just fine, until I get to an specific request, then I get the 401 error:

Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized , url=http://192.168.1.2:3000/companies/27.json}

Here is the route I'm trying to call, as implemented in my resquests service:

```
@GET("/companies/{company_id}.json")
 Call<Company> listCompany(@Path("company_id") int company_id);
```

Then in the activity I'm getting this 401 error, here's how I'm implementing its call:

```
UserSessionManager session = new UserSessionManager(context); //here I get my current local session. 
User user = session.getUser(); //my user model, at session.getUser() it returns all the correct data


MyRestService service = RestManager.getServiceWithHeaders(context);
Call<Company> call = service.listCompany(user.company_id);

call.enqueue(new Callback<Company>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Company> response, Retrofit retrofit) {         

        if(response.isSuccess()) {
            //it's NEVER getting here
           Company c = response.body();
            c.saveAll();

        } else {
            //it's falling here with the error:
            //Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized , url=http://192.168.1.2:3000/companies/27.json}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        //it's NOT falling here
    }
});
```

Just to illustrate things, if I call my authenticated methods from my chrome browser, after having the web application properly logged in, everything runs withouth any problem, then, if I logout
from the web application and try to perform the requests, I get exact the same output I'm getting from android. Which confirms to me that nothing is wrong with the API.

I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong. Retrofit's very new to me.

Here's my dependencies list from Gradle (the part that interests this issue):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.1'
}
```

UPDATE: As conversed before, the overall bug seemed to be a server bug. I took a while to find it but it was really there.

Just for documentation's sake, at my controller (rails), there's a devise validation (lib used for login strategies) which was excluding exactly the route I was using. Every other route was being tested against devise. So, it was like this:

```
enter code here`skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
```

and I changed it to this:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```

and everything's working smoothly now on Android's side.

Comment: did you try setting your logging to `BODY` level and seeing that headers are getting passed along along? logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

Comment: @bond I did, and it returns me the same error message:
"Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized , url=http://192.168.1.2:3000/companies/27.json}". In fact I have put the LoggingInterceptor.Level to HEADER just to check if I could get any different (better) message, without any luck.

Comment: @ClaudioFernandoMaciel can you debug to check **response-->rawResponse-->request** correct or not? You can also give a try to use Chrome extension-- Advanced Rest client to see whether your API call is exactly correct.

Comment: @ClaudioFernandoMaciel, few things you can try. Turn on debugger and stop where you do ` if (u.email != null) { `, if I were to guess, your email is coming in null and it is not setting the header it is expecting. Also try hitting the endpoint from Rest Client such as PostMan or PAW, see if API is responding to you correctly. 401 is un-authorized telling you that request does not have proper authentication headers.

Comment: @xiaoyaoworm I did get a bit more by using this rawResponse.request() method. Here's what I've got now:

response RAW: Request{method=GET, url=http://192.168.1.2:3000/companies/27.json, tag=Request{method=GET, url=http://192.168.1.2:3000/companies/27.json, tag=null}}

Comment: @bond I tried it and both my email and auth token are returning ok. I just can't seem to place a breakpoint into the interceptor's routines, it never stops there, I'm not sure why. Different thread maybe.

Comment: So, I executed this advanced rest client. I tried it with both a working route and this buggy route. Here are the printscreens:

https://beta.postimg.org/gallery/pzmzev6y/

In the first picture, I ran another authenticated route, passing my email and auth_token and it executed just fine.

Then I removed my email and auth_token and it broke. Then, with the auth_token and email, I tried to run my buggy route and it broke. It's starting to look like a broke route to me. More of a Rails problem than an android one. What do you guys think?

Comment: Ah, so then it looks like server side issue. From client u r passing the right headers. As you can see when you passed the email/token in ur 1st response u got 200, 2nd one u got 401 and on the last call you did have email/token and still got 401. so debug on server side why its giving u 401. Good Luck

Comment: Agree with bond, please check the server side, maybe your account doesn't   have access to such url: ****/company/***